# iOS Push Navigation Controller, without a bar on the second view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, pushviewcontroller

I have an iOS App, designed within a UINavigationController. One of the pushed view controllers, however, needs a full screen view, without the navigation bar on the top. (to get back, there is just a small, circular button). However, any method I've tried of 'hiding' the navigation bar (navigationCtl.navigationBar.hidden=TRUE) leaves me with ugly artifacts - calling that before the view is pushed (in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear) causes the previous view controllers bar to flash white just as the slide left animation starts. Similarly, calling it in viewDidAppear leaves a white bar at the top of the second view, along with several subviews pushed down, out of the way. Is there any way I can just have the new view slide over as it usually does, but when it comes over, there's simply no navigation bar up top?

---

Please note, to help Google, essentially the question here is:

How to animate between two UIViewControllers, when one has a navigation bar at the top, and the other one does not have a navigation bar at the top. So, how to navigate from a UIViewController with a navbar to one without a navbar - avoiding the horrible flickering.

The amazing answer is given below by Ev ... awesome.

Comment: Why not choose `presentViewController:animated:completion:` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

give this a spin and see how it works for you.

in the destination view controller in viewWillAppear

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

It actually has a cool effect and can be useful.  in the viewWillAppear everything happens before the view is displayed so it takes away the strange artifacts.

be well

Comment: Changing animated from NO to YES also fixes a bug where the navigation stack can get corrupt. With it set to NO, if you swipe from the left of the screen to go back, but then cancel your swipe, the navigation bar gets really screwed up.